# Same view for both create and edit in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Can we have a single razor view for both Create and Edit operations?

If yes, how do we achieve this?

Comment: What if I want to implement 1 view for creation, edition and visualization (read only) of a model? 3 different operations. Always 1 controller.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Sure you can.

On post, check in your controller whether the primary key has value 0 then Insert, otherwise Update.

View should be the same for Create and Edit.

Just remember to include:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.ID)
```

In your view

For example:

Model:

```
public class DescriptionModel
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

CreateEdit.cshtml:

```
@model DescriptionModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateEdit"))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model=> model.ID)
    @Html.EditorFor(model=> model.Description)
    <input type="submit" value='Submit' />
}
```

DescriptionModel controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View("CreateEdit", new DescriptionModel());
}
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    return View("CreateEdit", db.DescriptionModels.Find(id));
}

// Submit and add or update database
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateEdit(DescriptionModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       // No id so we add it to database
       if (model.ID <= 0)
       {
           db.DescriptionModels.Add(model);
       }
       // Has Id, therefore it's in database so we update
       else
       {
           db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
       }
       db.SaveChanges();
       return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: I believe this approach would be vulnerable to overposting attacks.  For example, a hacker could navigate to the edit page for their record and modify the value of the hidden field `DescriptionModel.ID` to point to another record that they shouldn't be able to access.  When they post the form, it will modify that other record instead of their own record.  [Bart's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25374200/1515372) outlines an alternative approach that addresses this security concern.

Comment: @Ifligus He could create some other Id that could be a guid, since its not a good practice expose the database ids via presentantion.

Comment: i think u can just use AddOrUpdate, then u don't even need to check, right?

Comment: According to [Julie Lerman](http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/take-care-with-ef-4-3-addorupdate-method/), the `AddOrUpdate` method was intended to prevent duplicates when running the seed during a migration.  Its use in a production environment could cause unexpected/undesired results.

Comment: @Ifligus You could address the security issue with a simple `if` statement. Something like (pseudocode) `if Model.User != currentUser then throw new ForbiddenException()` Id rather do this than maintain two relatively identical forms.

Answer (score 57):

I don't recommend it.

This should be a rather long answer, because there's a lot of things involved in the process, request and workflow of a normal MVC GET/POST workflow. I will try to answer your question with the minimum information required and why I do not recommend the use of the same view.

First, why?

1. You don't have control over the views, which may have over-posting;
2. No flexibility;
3. Not reusable views or parts;
4. Hard to maintain the views (one change in the view must be tested on both actions).

My suggested approach would be to have different actions/views but share common code:

Create both views as normal.

You will have duplicated code, but not all code is the same, for example, you may not want to send an ID on the create action, this is not directly related to your question, but using the same view implies you are also sending the same data, and this is not recommended, especially for over-posting or mass assignment. More info about mass assignment [here](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/03/12/complete-guide-to-mass-assignment-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx) (an Architectural Approach is what I'm using here).

So let's start from what are you going to receive in your controllers.
In this case I used inheritance but it's not the only strategy.

**Binding models**

```
public class UpdateBindingModel : CreateBindingModel {
    // since we are not using the same binding model, 
    // we can have a "real" validation rules on our update binding and view.
    [Required]
    public int? Id {get;set;}
}

public class CreateBindingModel {
    // no id here prevent overposting.
    [Required]
    public string Name {get;set;}
    [Required]
    public int? CountryId {get;set;}
}
```

That will make sure the data you send to your Create and Edit is the minimum needed and nothing else.

Let's then see the View Models that will be sent to the View, for this example I will include a List that will be used to select some value but should not be posted (the list) to the controller, only the selected value.

**View models**

```
public class CreateViewModel : CreateBindingModel {
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CountryList {get;set;}
}

public class UpdateViewModel : UpdateBindingModel {
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CountryList {get;set;}
}
```

As you can see, this gives you lot of flexibility but still have some duplicated code (the extra information needed on view model for both views) which can be mitigated in several ways (depending the needs/context):

1. Have an action to retrieve the common data and using `@Html.Action("GetCountryList");`
2. Use the same View Model aka `CreateUpdateViewModel` and discarding extra `UpdateBindingModel` properties in the view but still posting the corresponding model on POST.
3. Having your binding models as properties and select one or the other in the specific view. (better use `@Html.EditorFor` instead of partials so Model Binder will work with no additional change on code)

The controller actions will look like:

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create(){
    ViewData.Model = new CreateViewModel();
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public RedirectToRouteResult Create(CreateBindingModel binding) {
    // check valid model state and create data
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Update(int id) {
    var objectToEdit = service.GetObjectToEdit(id);
    ViewData.Model = new UpdateViewModel(objectToEdit);
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public RedirectToRouteResult Update(UpdateBindingModel binding) {
    // check valid model state and update data
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

And your views:

**Views**

```
Update.cshtml
<form action="Update">
    @Html.HiddenFor(Model.Id);
    @Html.Partial("EditFieldsPartial")
    <button>delete</button> // no delete button on create.
    <button>create new</button> // you can have a create new instead of update.
</form>

Create.cshtml
<form action="Create">
    @Html.Partial("EditFieldsPartial")
</form>
```

*Note:* code is incomplete and didn't use helpers in most cases for brevity and clarity. Do NOT copy paste :D

Comment: Shouldn't your `Update(int id)` function in Controller use UpdateBindingModel instead of CreateBindingModel to have the Id?

Comment: @brianestey nice catch. Fixed it, but instead of using the bindingmodel you should use your ViewModels. check the updated answer.

Comment: @BartCalixto in `Create` action, if `ModelState` is invalid, how can we return `Create.cshtml` view ? (it requires `CreateViewModel` but in `Create` action we only have `CreateBindingModel`)

Comment: @tchelidze return Create()

Comment: @BartCalixto Crete() will return empty create view, instead we want view with populated data (that was invalid)

Comment: @tchelidze It will execute the `GET` create method on your controller and will create the ViewModel properly. ModelState is preserved so you should see validation errors on your view.

Comment: @BartCalixto Yes, it wil lexecute `GET` request but in `Create` action, we are not binding to data. instead we are instantiating new model ` ViewData.Model = new CreateViewModel();` which will be empty data

Comment: @tchelidze you validation errors are on ModelState, not on your ViewModel. just try it, it works.

Comment: @BartCalixto LOVE this answer.

Comment: I'm lost on how the form can be put into a partial view and be called by two different Razor pages with two different models ("CreateViewModel" and "UpdateViewModel"). You can't declare a model in the partial view because you don't know which one is being used?  I wish you'd show the code for the partial view. It would help newcomers, a lot.

Comment: @PhilNicholas I ran into this and used an interface which defined the common fields to be used in the partial. Both CreateViewModel and UpdateViewModel have the interface defined. Then model interfacename in the partial. [Display] attributes must be placed on the interface but this seems to work okay with minimal duplication.

Answer (score 3):

A View can definitely be shared for create and edit operations, using the same model. **However**, i would strongly recommend to think about it twice. In many cases, you will want to have a different view for edit operations(eg. hide some inputs that should not be editible) as well as the model could be slightly different, altought it might share some (or most) values. These difference will lead to some conditions in the view, checking whether you are creating or editing - which could make the code chaotic.
**Conclusion:** before deciding whether to have a shared view, try to think of how much is the edit screen gonna differ from create screen, then you may decide.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend that approach but you could have the main form be loaded into both views from a partial

Answer (score 2):

You certainly can, but usually that's something I will try to avoid. If the create and edit actions are virtually the same then you end up duplicating a lot of code in the controller. Usually in this situation I will have only a few fields on my 'Add' controller, and then once the item has been added I redirect the user to the edit page where they can fill in the rest of the information.

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpGet]
 public ActionResult myFun(int id = 0)
        {
            MyClass cls = new MyClass();
            if (id == 0)
            {
                //Insert mode ... no data will be shown to textboxes , when primary key ie. id=0
               //Display whole data
            }
            else
            {
                //Update mode... if id is not 0 ,data will be shown to textboxes
            }

            return View(cls);
        }
```